# How to compute stride mean in Pytorch?

Tags: pytorch

For example, we have `x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` with `stride = 3`, `step = 1`, then the stride mean would be `result = [2, 3, 4]`. More specifically, I have a vector with `shape = (batch_size, sequence_len, embed_dim)`, and I want to perform the above operation on `dim = 1` (`sequence_len`). How can I implement that efficiently in PyTorch?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you mean - in PyTorch notation - is a kernel size of *3* and a stride of *1*. You can use [`torch.nn.AvgPool1d`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.AvgPool1d.html?highlight=avgpool1d#torch.nn.AvgPool1d) to perform this kind of operation:

```
mean = nn.AvgPool1d(kernel_size=3, stride=1)
```

Note, you will need one extra dimension, for the channel, to be compatible with this kind of layer:

```
>>> x = torch.tensor([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]).unsqueeze(0)
tensor([[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]])

>>> mean(x)
tensor([[[2, 3, 4]]])
```